# C: Read file and store word by word in 2d array

Tags: arrays, c, file

I am trying to read from txt file word by word, and store it in a 2d array so I could print and use them one by one. I also tried using fscanf and malloc but I'm not sure how to use properly. Here's What I've tried so far:

```
#define SIZE_OF_DECK 54
    char buffer[100][200];
    FILE *fptr = fopen(argv[1],"r");
    if (fptr == NULL){
        printf("Error creating file");
        exit(1);
    }
    int count=0;
    while (count < SIZE_OF_DECK && fgets(buffer[count],200,fptr) != NULL){
        count++;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i<SIZE_OF_DECK; i++){
        printf("Elements %d : %s\n", buffer[i]);
    }
    fclose(fptr);
    return 0;
```

The txt file contains something like

```
S1 S2 S3 S4 S5 A1 A2 A3 A4 A5
```

So What I exepcted is to be like

```
Elements 0: S1
Elements 1: S2
...
..
```

Any suggestion would be helpful, Thanks

Comment: Currently, your `fgets` reads up to 200 characters to store them in `buffer[count]`. If each of the elements contains only 2 characters, the argument of `fgets` should be changed accordingly.

Comment: If you want to store every word individually and still have a connection between each line and words it contains, than you will need something more than 2d array, like structures and arrays.  but if you only need to parse words for printing (not storing), than you can use `fgets` / `strtok` or just `fgetc` / `putchar`. I found posts by David C. Rankin to be helpful. He wrote a lote about parsing text. https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3422102+line+words

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, a little bit different than yours but it works fine;

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
 
int main() 
{ 
    FILE* textFile; 
    textFile = fopen("text.txt","r");       //filename of your data file 
    char buffer[100][50];           //max word length 50 
    int i = 0; 
    while(1){ 
        char r = (char)fgetc(textFile); 
        int k = 0; 
        while(r != ' ' && !feof(textFile)){ //read till , or EOF 
            buffer[i][k++] = r;         //store in array , 2 character in this example and k+1 (go to next column)
            r = (char)fgetc(textFile); 
        } 
        buffer[i][k]=0;     //make last character of string null  
        if(feof(textFile)){     //check again for EOF 
            break; 
        } 
        i++; // go to the next row
    } 
    for(int j = 0;j<=i;j++){ 
        printf("Element %d: %s\n", j + 1, buffer[j] );  //print array 
    } 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Works sort of. It doesn't recognize newlines or spaces before first word. Seems also wasteful with space.